# Are micro- and nanotechnology related questions on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Are micro- and nanotechnology (and micro- and nanosciences) related questions on-topic here?

Some example questions could be

1. How do you manufacture carbon nanotubes with a specific chirality?
2. I want to etch silicon micropillars with RIE. Suppose the diameter is 2 µm. How deep structures can I make with a photoresist mask?
3. What is the practical upper temperature limit for a silicon microdevice process after Al-deposition?
4. How large silicene sheets can be manufactured?
5. What is the practical resolution limit of DUV lithography?

Comment: As always there is overlap with others like physics.SE but it is also within engineering. I would ask them. The general problem that there is much overlap between all the applied and pure sciences.. needs to be solved on a higher level, I guess.

Comment: I would be concerned that some of your examples would require answers that are too broad / too long for the SE Q&A format, but otherwise those appear to be good, valid questions for the site.

Answer (score 3):

These all seem like reasonable questions to me.

You might get better answers to 1) elsewhere (Chemistry?) but I don't know enough about the topic to give a definite answer. Should be on topic here too though.

2-5) all seem on topic and here is probably the best place I could think to ask them (although you could possibly get answers from Chemistry/Physics).